# Recoding multiple rows in an order approach in R

Tags: r, excel

Here is an example of my data with the outcome of interest

```
V1  V2    V3    V4   V1OUT   V2OUT   V3OUT   V4OUT
X   WER   123   WE     1       4       6      10
X   WOT   145   ZZ     1       5       8      10
12  WER   123   WE     3       4       6      9
11  WER   145   WE     2       4       8      9
12  WER   134   ZZ     3       4       7      10
11  WOT   134   ZZ     2       5       7      10
```

I want to recode my data in an order way.

For example,
Column A, variable 1 (v1), I have 3 groups ( X, 11,12).

I want to recode X=1, 11=2,12=3. This will reflect in V1OUT.

In column B (V2) i have 2 groups, WER and WOT, so WER=4, WOT=5, this will reflect in V2OUT and etc.

Is it possible to do it in R. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In E2:

```
=1+(LEFT(A2)="1")+(RIGHT(A2)="2")
```

in F2:

```
=4+(B2="WOT")
```

both copied down to suit.

Comment: This does not work for me ,  it is also wrong sorry if you have different names in rows@ pnuts

Comment: I have changed the title to R  as it seems that it is not possible in Excel